# Xcode - set values of objects in array using for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to store multiple variables (float/int?) in a NSarray/NSMutableArray and then using a for loop add a value of 0.25 to the first int/float/NSNumber, 0.50 to the second, 0.75 to the third, 1.0 to the forth and so on.  I will have around 15 variables (give or take)

can anyone help me please, if it is a floast i will declare them in my header file as

```
@property float *value1;
@property float *value2;
```

and so on......

implementation file

initially set each value to 0? then how do i add to array and add the new values?

Comment: 1) Your properties are wrong. Get rid of the asterisks. Do not use pointers for primitive types like `float`. 2) Please do some research and try something. Post what you have attempted. Describe where you need help.

Comment: And why bother with an NSArray if it's just an array of floats? Use a C array of floats, and you won't have to bother dereferencing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Hope the array has a number of NSNumbers, Then to add 0.25 multiples

```
 for(NSInteger i=0;i<array.count;i++){

        NSNumber *value=(NSNumber *)[array objectAtIndex:i] ;
        float l=[value floatValue] + i*0.25;
        value=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:l];
        [array setObject:value atIndexedSubscript:i];

  }
```

IF you want to add elements with value '0'to array,

```
for(NSInteger i=0;i<15;i++){

    NSNumber *value=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    [array setObject:value atIndexedSubscript:i];
}
```